# Uninstalling Windows using gparted and grubcustomizer?

Tags: grub2, windows, uninstall

Would it be safe to delete the "Windows" partition and then removing it from grub using grubcustomizer.
I'm using Windows and Ubuntu in dual-boot but I don't need Windows anymore.

Comment: Grub customizer is also not required sudo update-grub should do the job. Just don't touch the EFI System Partition

Comment: I'd recommend keeping Windows, even if you don't regularly use it. You'll need it to do BIOS/firmware updates, or update devices like Garmin GPS, which only makes software that runs on Windows.